# multipart POST with Airborne, failing with "Missing start boundary"

Tags: ruby, rspec, rest-client, airborne

Been using rest-client for some time now, but new to Airborne. The snag I've hit is that I can't seem to get multi-part post for file upload working with Airborne. I wind up with a bad request 'Missing start boundary' My Airborne POST looks like this:

```
  before :all do
    fyle = File.new("e:/some-file.jpg", 'rb')
    body = {:profile => "KonflictME", :file => fyle, :multipart => true}
    post "/uploads", body, { :content_type => 'multipart/form-data' }
  end
```

My working example using rest-client looks like this:

```
fyle = File.new("e:/some-file.jpg, 'rb')
resp = RestClient.post base_path_api << "uploads",
  {:profile => "KonflictME", :file => fyle, :multipart => true},
  {:authorization => "myTokenString}
```

Not a lot of difference between the two, shouldn't be since rest-client is used under the hood for Airborne. *For Airborne, base_url and headers are setup in config (spec_helper.rb)*.

Has anyone else tried a multi-part post with Airborne? Uploads are only a small part of my test suite and I have a non-Airborne solution (just use rest-client directly for these tests), but would like to keep things simple for the rest of team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

airborne framework is based on restclient, and in the source code there is a line in lib/airborne/rest_client_requester.rb:

`request_body = request_body.to_json if options[:body].is_a?(Hash)`

which means every body you have defined will be transfered into json, and as a parameter in follow line:

`RestClient.send(method, get_url(url), request_body, headers)`

But in restclient, you don't need to consider the pattern of body whether you want to post a json or upload a file. If you want to upload a file you can change the above code to:

`request_body = request_body.to_json if options[:body].is_a?(Hash) && options[:body].to_json["file"].nil?`

to check if body you defined contains a file. I have made this change in my recent project.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestClient (a dependency of airborne) to make this fairly easy. Write out your params as normal with a hash:

```
params = {
              other_param: 'Some param',
              file: File.new(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'sample.csv'), 'r')
          }
      }

multipart = RestClient::Payload::Multipart.new(params)
post endpoint, params: multipart.read, headers: multipart.headers
```